# How to make a dictionary from a file

Tags: python, file, dictionary, io

my file is in a folder that contains text documents that have an image. The file "stars" contains A.txt

my goal is to get a dictonary that will say {'A', A.txt } the A.txt being a path to the actually file A.txt

```
import os




def main():

    # relative path to the folder where you unzipped the ASCII art files
    #folder = "stars"
    # or use an absolute path to the folder. example:
    folder = r"C:\Users\Alison\Documents\a CPS 111\Bonus PA\stars\stars"

    # os.listdir(folder) returns a list of files in folder
    file_list = os.listdir(folder)
    letter_art = {}



    for fname in file_list:
        # example: letter[0] is "A" and letter[1] is "txt"
        letter_extension_list = fname.split(".")
        key = letter_extension_list[0]

        value = letter_extension_list[1]
        value = "%s."%(key) + value 

        letter_art[key] = value 
        fname = "\\".join([folder, value])
    word = str(input("Please input a letter: "))  
    word = word.upper()
    for letter in word:
        print(letter_art[letter])



        print(fname)


main()
```

I am really struggling with making the directory work, because I will eventual get to a point where the user will input a word and it will output a drawing based on the letters from the files located in stars.

so the file in folder contains a text document associated with a letter. There are 26 documents A-Z A.txt, B.txt ect...

the goal is to create a dictionary saying {'A', A.txt}
so if the user enter "hi" the computer find h.txt and i.txt and display the information in the text file.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, and I have no idea what your goal is with those loops.

Comment: I am trying to make a dictonary from the file. But as you can probably tell, I am very stuck. I guess I'm mostly confused on how to assign something as the key and something as the value. The loops are just to read through the file, because there are multiple lines @TigerhawkT3

Comment: I still don't know what your actual task is, but not a single line of that code makes logical sense to me. Perhaps you can clarify your task by providing the theoretical result if you were to print the dictionary you're trying to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your present goal is to get a dictionary where the key is the Alphabet and the value is the filepath, you could try this:

```
import os
folder = r"C:\Users\sarah\Documents\a CPS 111\Bonus PA\stars\stars"

file_list = os.listdir(folder)
letter_art = {}

for fname in file_list:
    letter_extension_list = fname.split(".")
    key = letter_extension_list[0]
    fp = folder + '\\' + fname
    letter_art[key] = fp

entry = raw_input()
for letter in entry:
    print letter_art[letter]
```

Comment: This worked! could you explain to me what the line
fp = folder + '\\' + fname does?

Comment: Also when I run the code it gives me the location file of all the letters, how would I manipualte this so the code only gives me specific letters? @Yash Dhandhania

Comment: fp combines the folder name and the file name to give you the file path which is then being assigned as the value for a given key.

Comment: Which specific letters are you looking for? In all probability you're going to have to hard code it unless there's a pattern to the letters

Comment: Thats going to be a problem then, because the user can input anything. Well thats going to be the end goal of this code

Comment: So you're saying the user will input a letter? In that case change that print statement at the end to `print letter_art[input]`

Comment: i get an error     `KeyError: <built-in function input>`

Comment: I fixed the error, and it gives me the correct response. If the user inputs 'hi' is there any way to get h.txt and i.txt to be returned by using the .split function? I have also updated my code to what I currently have running.

Comment: awesome It seems to be working correctly, except all the code returns `C:\Users\Alison\Documents\a CPS 111\Bonus PA\stars\stars\Z.txt` 
instead of changing the letter according to the word only runs "Z"
I've updated my code as well

Comment: Before taking the input, print the letter_art dictionary and check that that's all right

Comment: `key = letter_extension_list[0]` is running all the way through the alphabet and its not stopping on the inputted letter, making key = "Z" for this code
`value = letter_extension_list[1]
  value = "%s."%(key) + value `

Comment: @sarahcampolt so you're saying that the dictionary isn't all right before you take the user's input?

Comment: Yeah, the loop is causing the variable Key to always be Z, I need to find a way to get key to index the correct letter based on what is inputted.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your overwriting `key`. First its the filename e.g. "A" but if the name was "AB" then the key will cause issues (e.g. accessing key[1]), but perhaps you don't encounter this situation.

Also `letter_art[key]` doesn't appear to be doing anything in the loop "#to get all A-Z as the keys". Is this old code?

Later on the value is also overwritten without doing anything, are you just trying to get the last line?

Are you just trying to achieve what @Yash Dhandhania answered?

Comment: my code under #to get all A-Z as the keys is my attempt to run through all the indexes to get A , B, C, but this seemed to be the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

**After EDIT**

```
import os
folder = r"C:\Users\sarah\Documents\a CPS 111\Bonus PA\stars\stars"

file_list = os.listdir(folder)
print(file_list)
letter_art = {}

file_list.sort()

for fname in file_list:
    letter_extension_list = fname.split(".")
    key = letter_extension_list[0]
    letter_art[key]=folder+'\'+fname

print(letter_art)

word=raw_input('Input : ')
letters=list(word)

for letter in letters:
    if letter in letter_art:
        print("**File : %s***\n"%letter)
        with open(letter_art[letter]) as f:
            print f.read()
```

Comment: It is being added to a dictionary, the order does not matter as dictionaries are not sorted.

Comment: @sarahcampolt it sorts the list of alphabets, but this will not help you because a dictionary does not maintain its order. You then want to change your dictionary to an OrderedDict for that.

Comment: @sarahcampolt Check now.. Does that solve your doubts?